# Django open html page from backend

Tags: python, html, django

How can I display an html page if an event is triggered at the backend with django?

direction.py

```
    # render error html if list is empty
    if len(waypoint) == 0:
    print("Trip not possible with selected specs : Not enough charging stations")
    #open error.html page
```

views.py

```
    def error(request):
       return render(request, 'routing/error.html')
```

urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^error/$', views.error),
    ]
```

Comment: Create a view that renders html templates based on the result from direction.py

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are doing here. What is direction.py? How are its functions being called?

Comment: the direction.py is running without problems, I just want to call the error function from there to display the error.html site if the waypoint list is emtpy